# What's the source for a rabbinic statement that 'when one country expels the Jews, another lets them in'?

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, rishonim, anti-semitism

I'm very confident that I once saw a statement from a rabbi (probably in the Medieval era, but maybe later) to the effect that "God has ensured that when one country expels its Jewish population, another country will allow Jews to live there," so that the Jews are never completely homeless. Does anyone know of such a source?

Comment: We have an answer on this site attributing the concept to Rav Samuel Hirsch with the exact citation, but I can't seem to find it right now

Comment: וְאַף-גַּם-זֹאת בִּהְיוֹתָם בְּאֶרֶץ אֹיְבֵיהֶם, לֹא-מְאַסְתִּים וְלֹא-גְעַלְתִּים לְכַלֹּתָם--לְהָפֵר בְּרִיתִי, אִתָּם:  כִּי אֲנִי ה', אֱלֹהֵיהֶם.

Comment: answered here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/138208/exile-helped-the-jews-to-survive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rabbenu Nissim of Gerona expresses this idea. Derashoth ha-Ran (1):

> עד שהראשון שהתחיל זה והוא אברהם קרה לו מה שקרה עם נמרוד עד שהוצרך
> לעזוב ארצו וללכת אל ארץ אחרת ואין ספק שאותם צדיקים שהיו יחידים בדורות
> ההם היה להם חילוק האומות והממשלות לטוב ולתועלת כי **כאשר תצר להם האמונה
> באיזה מלכות ישוטטו אל ארץ אחרת שיוכלו שם לעבוד ה' יתברך כרצונם כאשר
> קורה לנו בגלותנו היום כי כאשר נתחדש שמד בארץ ישמעאל נסו פליטיהם אל ארץ
> אדום ומאדום לישמעאל וזה אצלנו מחיה מעם בעבדותינו**

> So that the first to begin this call, Abraham, experienced what he did
> at the hands of Nimrod until he was compelled to leave his land and go
> to a different one. Now, unquestionably, for those righteous men who
> were unique in those generations the division of peoples and kingdoms
> was a good and a benefit. **For when the people of a certain kingdom
> would oppress them, they would move on to a different land, where they
> could serve the Lord as they desired, as is the case in our present
> day exile. For when enforced conversion began in the Ishmaelite lands,
> the Jews fled to the lands of Edom, and from [the lands of] Edom, back to [the lands of]
> Ishmael. And this gave us a lease on life in the midst of our
> afflictions and our toils.**

There may be others as well.

Comment: Thanks! There may indeed be others, but this is exactly what I had read a few months ago and couldn't remember where it was

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the [link](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/138208/2106) to the previous post, where I posted the above answer of the דרשות הר"ן and where Rav Hirsch's comment was also mentioned